# How to take PostgreSQL Database Backup and find the location of Backed up Database in Digital Ocean(Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I have taken a backup of PostgreSQL database using

```
pg_dump dbname > dbname.bak
```

now, how do I download it to my local PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I foung answer.
In Ubuntu, try this

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump db_name > db_name.bak
```

and find backup in `/var/lib/postgresql`

Comment: Thanks for this answer.you really save my time